# What does the sharp and exclamation mark (#!) stand for in a url? Don't even know how to look for an answer

Tags: ajax, hash

I have seen these "domain.com/#!/" formated urls, and driven merely by curiosity I chose to ask you people... what is that used for? A kinda "exclamated-hashtag" if you know what I mean.
I see it on sites such as "hypem.com" or "buzzchips.com", both of them delivering asynchronous dynamic content in a similar way.

I uploaded a tiny shot just so you actually see what I see, [here](http://i51.tinypic.com/2v0zpqc.png) and [there](http://i54.tinypic.com/2co54yg.png).

Answer (score 11):

It appears to be a [standard](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) for allowing dynamically created content to be crawled.

Comment: Many thanks, very informative. This is where i'll start if I need to implement this standard.

Comment: The link is very important. May be it is better if you quote at least the **Hash fragments** and **Pretty URL** sections just in case the link would broke in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can see a good explanation of this under the SEO heading for the following answer:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site/46760#46760

Comment: Nice link! Thanks for the added-value on the answer.

Comment: Usage of #! is now deprecated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Proposals
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?csw=1 (notice it's deprecated)